# Host url validation using preg_match

Tags: regex, validation, url, preg-match

This is my actual function:

```
public function _validate_host($url)
{
    $pattern = "/^([w]{2}([\w\-]+\.)?([\w]{2,5}))(:[\d]{1,5})?/";
    if (!preg_match($pattern, $url))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Live working demo: http://regexr.com?300ag

Actual pattern does select only an url like:

```
www.my-url.com
```

I want it to match the host urls like:

```
my-url.com - if found, match.
my.server.com - if found, match.
www.my-url.com - if found, match.

http://www.my-url.com/ - if www.my-url.com found, match.
```

It should also ignore (while checking) the `http://` (if appended) and then it should replace fe. the following url: `http://www.my-url.com/` to the `www.my-url.com`.

Any solutions will be appreciated.

Comment: `return TRUE / FALSE` depending on `if` condition ? Seriously ?

Comment: @hsz nah, thats just a scretch, what it should match.

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?
```

or

```
[a-z\-\:\/\.]+
```

this will pick up URLs even if they have http://  however you could use a str_replace in php to remove the http:// from the result.

Comment: Your second pattern not seems to work properly. But the first one is good, but it its invalid in some cases like: `my-url.com/` - it should not pass such url because there is an slash `/` at the end, could you fix that?

Answer (score 0):

i am work by this:)

```
function validate_url($domain)
{    
    if(preg_match('|^http(s)?://[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$|i', $domain))
        return $domain;
    else
        return false;    
}
```